# Zsh: Command Not found : mongo After trying to install mongodb 4.2 using brew

Tags: database, mongodb, mongodb-query, homebrew, zsh

I have tried the following steps to install and setup mongodb in my mac from here https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-os-x/ but I got the following error when running the final "**mongo**" command in my terminal:

**Error Message -  Zsh: Command Not found : mongo**

This error msg occurred after trying to install mongodb 4.2 using brew

```
sudo chown -R $(whoami) $(brew --prefix)/*

then

brew tap mongodb/brew

then

brew install mongodb-community@4.2

and

brew services start mongodb-community@4.2

or

mongod --config /usr/local/etc/mongod.conf

then

ps aux | grep -v grep | grep mongod

and

mongo
```

running **brew services start mongodb-community@4.2** returns:

```
Successfully started `mongodb-community@4.2` (label: homebrew.mxcl.mongodb-community@4.2)
```

running **ps aux | grep -v grep | grep mongod** returns:

```
9081   0.2  0.5  5528024  41856   ??  S     3:01pm   0:01.48 /usr/local/opt/mongodb-community@4.2/bin/mongod --config /usr/local/etc/mongod.conf

7613   0.0  0.1  4298832   5600 s000  T     2:47pm   0:00.08 vim /usr/local/etc/mongod.conf
```

**running mongod --config /usr/local/etc/mongod.conf returns:**

```
zsh: command not found: mongod
```

There are also no mongo files in my /usr/local/bin directory after using these commands

I created a data/db folder in my /usr/local/bin directory using the following commands:

```
sudo mkdir -p  /usr/local/bin/data/db   
sudo chown -R `id -un`  /usr/local/bin/data/db
```

Running "**brew update**" returns:

```
brew update                                                                                                                                                    
Updated 1 tap (homebrew/cask).
==> Updated Casks
brave-browser
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved it by manually installing the mongodb community files and db tools using the website instead. Then copying them into /usr/local/bin. Then ignoring the app permissions whenever calling mongo or related commands in the terminal through System Preferences > Security & Privacy > General.

After googling I found out that mongoimport and the other features have to be installed separately: https://www.mongodb.com/try/download/database-tools

Followed by copying those bin files after extracting them into the same /usr/local/bin directory

Not sure why its' not working through homebrew though

Answer (score 6):

`brew install mongodb-community-shell`

Fixed the problem for me.

Answer (score 3):

**This worked for me, I was having same issue on mongodb-community@4.4**

```
 brew reinstall mongodb-community@4.4
```

On terminal something like this will appear during reinstallation.

[image]

copy highlighted path with echo

```
 echo 'export PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/mongodb-community@4.4/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc
```

Now open another terminal and start mongodb services

```
brew services restart mongodb/brew/mongodb-community@4.4
```

write mongo on terminal and here we fly

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you installed the mongodb via Homebrew. Need to add the mongo path in your bash_profile.

- Edit the bash_profile vi ~/.bash_profile
- Add the below line in EOF export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/opt/mongodb-community@4.2/bin
- After the edit bash_profile. Close all terminals and open them again. mongo command start works.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @ramesh-babu-t-b 's answer, https://stackoverflow.com/a/68407530/1279516, the issue could also be that your MongoDB installation *did* add `mongod` to your path, but the installation happened within the current shell session, and so your shell doesn't have the updates to the `PATH` variable yet.

In this case, only his last step is still necessary - Open a new console window and retry the `mongod` command.